# Ativar thumbnail via ajax

Tags: fancybox

Pessoal estou carregando uma galeria de imagens via AJAX com o fancybox so que eu preciso também colocar os thumbnails nesta galeria como eu devo proceder?

Retorno do meu JSON:

> [{"title":"legenda 1.....aa","href":"553e2ec2a7be4.jpg"},{"title":"legenda 1.","href":"553f7d3c4bed5.jpg"},{"title":"legenda 1.","href":"553f7d4924889.jpg"},{"title":"legenda 1.","href":"553f7d5770577.jpg"},{"title":"legenda 1.","href":"553f7d6459659.jpg"}]

Meu JS

```
$('#maisAlbuns').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.getJSON( "/fotos/3", function( data ) {
    $.fancybox(data,[
        {
            helpers: {
                thumbs: {
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    source: function (current) {
                        return $(current.element).data('href');
                    }
                }
            }
        }]);
});
```

});